# How many iterations does this loop perform?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

This is the question that I failed in my exam. My answer was 9 times as I counted that the loop will do one more round to check whether the conditions are false and only after that it exits the enhanced loop.

```
int array[] = {81,13,10,34,23,234,8,33};
int value = array[0]; 
int value2 = value;
for (int element : array){
    if (element > value){
        value = element;
    }
    if (element < value2){
        value2 = element;
    }
}
```

Can you help me to clarify the exact number of times the loop works and whether it checks at the last round the conditions even when the element equals to 33?

Comment: "as I counted that the loop will do one more round to check [...]" that was your error, it doesn't

Comment: Can't you just put a counter and print it ?

Comment: it's 8, try it out?

Comment: executes once for each element in the array.

Comment: Definitely 8. If you want to know whether the last condition is evaluated (which, why wouldn't it be?), drop this code into your IDE and use the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this program and check the answer.

```
int count=0;
        int array[] = {81,13,10,34,23,234,8,33};
        int value = array[0];
        int value2 = value;
        for (int element : array){
            if (element > value){
                value = element;
            }
            if (element < value2){
                value2 = element;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Loop is executed " + count + " times");
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `for (int element : array)` means that you'll make **an iteration** for **each value** one by one, so you'll the same amount of iteration than the amount of values, which is 8

Answer (score 0):

8 is the answer because although the condition will be checked for the ninth time, the program won't go into the loop since the condition isn't satisfied.